# android setting up lock screen widget

Tags: android, android-widget, lockscreen, android-version, lockscreenwidget

I need to develop an app including feature to add widget on lock screen. 
I tried that on 3 devices so far -

1) Samsung Galaxy s4 (KitKat 4.4) - It worked well, if the lock is swipe screen lock,
   but doesn't work in case of pattern lock. Even in case of swipe lock, I am unable to add it on main lock screen, instead it appears on second or third screen, navigated from the main lock screen to its right.

2) Samsung Galaxy Grand (JB 4.2.2) - same behaviour as above.

3) LG ls970 (JB 4.1) - It doesn't seem to provide lock screen widget feature at all.

So, what must I do in case I need that to be worked in most of the devices.

What may be the issue by the way - Is it version specific issue or the brand specific or both.

Please let me know the solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lock screen Widgets is not provided by "default" in "older" versions of Android.

Speaking of older - ALL DEVICES THAT ARE >= Android 4.2 SUPPORT lock screen widgets.

OLDER devices < Android 4.2 does NOT SUPPORT this feature. That's the problem

You can get more information on this topic here: [Lock screen Widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

And btw, make sure just to read more on the Google's provided information about Android. It supports search too!

[Basics of Android by Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)